# React/Flux seState not re-rendering component after API call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux, reactjs-flux

I am making a call to an API that allows you to sort the data it returns by different parameters e.g top, latest, popular and so on. What i'm trying to achieve is that when a user clicks a button to sort by a different parameter, the state is changed to the new parameter and the API is called again with that new parameter. Here's my code:

```
constructor (){
    super();
    this.state = {
        sortType: 'top' //default is to sort by Top
    };

    this.setSortType = this.setSortType.bind(this);
}
componentWillMount(){
    //this retrieves sourceName which is required to make the API call
    const parsed = queryString.parse(this.props.location.search);
    var sourceName = parsed.sourceId;

    //getArticles below is the action that makes the API call with sourcename and sortType as parameters  

    newsActions.getArticles(sourceName,this.state.sortType);
    newsStore.on('articles_change',this.fetchNewsArticles);

}
//Call to setState when user clicks button change sort parameter
setSortType(){
    this.setState({
        sortType:'latest'
    });
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
        ... //logic to display data from the API call 
        <button onClick={this.setSortType}> Sort By Latest </button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

When the button is clicked nothing re-renders. What i'm i missing?

Answer (score 0):

React calls `componentWillMount` just once on component mount, so the logic it contains won't be updated executed again on state change.

Have a look to [React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html), to a better understand of how React licecycle hooks work.